# What is the maximum length of a character function argument in jython?

Tags: python, jython

What is the maximum length of a character function argument in python/jython?

I've reviewed the documentation on python.org and no luck

Comment: What's a character function?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @Carl I think he means a function argument that is a string of characters.

Comment: I thought maybe it was http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch11_01.htm

Answer (score 3):

Python passes function arguments by reference, so the maximum length of a string passed to a function is purely dependent on the maximum length of a string.

It so happens that the maximum length of a string is platform dependent (Address space and/or RAM, generally) - see the question [What is the max length of a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string) for details.

In python (and I'd assume this would work in jython as well) you can find out this value with `sys.maxsize`:

```
>>>import sys
>>>print sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
```

From the docs:

> maxsize: The largest positive integer supported by the platform’s Py_ssize_t type, and thus the maximum size lists, strings, dicts, and many other containers can have.

Your max length string will not be anywhere near this many characters, mind you.

Comment: @Carl Hopefully, even if I miss, it's a reasonable swing!