# What is this code doing? (size_t)-1

Tags: c++

Can someone explain what happens when size_t, or any other type identifier, is wrapped in parentheses. I know it is the old typecast syntax but in this context I don't follow what is happening.

I've seen it for defining the max size of a type as:

```
size_t max_size = (size_t)-1
```

Comment: It is a C-style cast. It casts `-1` to `size_t`, which presumably yields a very large number.

Comment: @juanchopanza: To be precise, the max number that `size_t` can represent :)

Comment: The cast is unnecessary. `size_t max_size = -1;` does the same thing.

Comment: @VladLazarenko assuming two's complement :)

Comment: @juanchopanza: The C++ standard specifies that `size_t` is unsigned (because it inherits specifications about it from C) and that unsigned integer types use modulo arithmetic.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, this is standardized.

Comment: @KerrekSB Interesting. I thought there was some leeway for one's complement implementations, presumably for archaeological reasons. I must have been misinformed.

Comment: @juanchopanza: There is leeway in signed types.

Comment: @jtetm Anyway, the C++ way to get the maximum value of `size_t` would be `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You can have one's complement, but it means more work when you convert signed to unsigned...

Comment: Why (size_t)-1 fields to the max number of size_t?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code (unnecessarily) casts `-1` to `size_t`. The most probable intent was getting the largest possible value of `size_t`  on this system.

Although this code doesn't have Undefined Behavior, this code is ugly - in C++ you should use `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` and in C use `SIZE_MAX` macro for exactly a purpose of getting the largest `size_t` value.

Comment: This code has well-defined behaviour. You might not like it, but it's sanctioned by the standard. (Both C and C++ standards, in fact.) And in C++ (the OP tag), you should use `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`

Answer (score 1):

`(size_t)-1` is in fact the equivalent of `size_t(-1)`

See also the following question [c cast syntax styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles)

Answer (score 0):

Some library methods intentionally return `(size_t)(-1)` to indicate an error condition.  For example, [the iconv method from the GNU libiconv library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.9.1/iconv.3.html).  I assume there is some good reason why these functions don't return `ssize_t` (signed) return values, which would allow you to check for -1 directly.

Comment: You wouldn't want to dedicate 16 bit only for the negative error codes.

Answer (score 0):

for one of the code snippet I have encountered, size_t-1 aimed simply to have -1. They wanted to terminate for negative values.

The code snippet is bellow.

```
while (len != (size_t)-1) 
{
    mod = num % 16;
    if (mod < 10)
        str[len] = mod + '0';
    else if (mod >= 10)
        str[len] = (mod - 10) + 'a';
    num = num / 16;
    len--;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).