# safe to assign uint32_t variable to a signed value

Tags: c, types

I recently came across a code where

```
                uint32_t index = -1;
```

Is this safe to use the above.Assume that the code will have to be compiled across multiple Linux platforms and distributions.Or is it recommended to use a signed value?
if I compare it against -1 somewhere in the program is it likely to compare -1 with 0xffffffff and throw an error or manifest some other strange behaviour.

Comment: What value do you expect? And how do you define safe?

Comment: it is recommended coding practice?  if I compare it against -1 somewhere in the program is it likely to compare -1 with 0xffffffff and throw an error etc

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/50605/214671

Comment: Didn't we just have this question [a few minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19234248/596781)?