# Do Dictionaries have a key length limit?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering if Python had a limit on the length of a dictionary key.

For clarification, I'm not talking about the number of keys, but the length of each individual key.  I'm going to be building my dictionaries based on dynamic values (after validation), but I'm not sure if I should be taking length into account in this case.

Comment: As long as the keys are hashable you shouldn't have troubles IMHO.

Comment: When you say "length" do you mean length of a string?  Because you can have non-string keys, so it may be better to ask your question in terms of memory size

Comment: In this instance I mean string length.  I know that you can have non-string keys, but I was thinking that the limits may be comparable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no such limit in place regarding dictionary keys. Since python also has arbitrary precision on numeric types, the only limit you will encounter, string or otherwise, is that of available memory. You can see another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string) for a discussion on maximum string length in python 2.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a bit of sample code:

```
from string import ascii_letters
from random import choice

def make_str(length):
    return "".join(choice(ascii_letters) for i in range(length))

test_dict = {make_str(10000000): i for i in range(5)}
```

Conclusion: Python will quite happily use a 10-million-character string as a dict key.

Answer (score 1):

As I know there's no limit but consider that more the key is long, the more the time to create/access the keys

Comment: If you already have the object in memory, storing its reference in the dictionary won't add much overhead. And hashing the key may not depend on the size of it.

Comment: I've primarily used string keys in my dictionaries and I've seen that going over 30-40 characters the performance were slightly decreasing

Comment: @AlexF Off the top of my head, it could be that the equals checks, which are needed to protect agains hash collisions, are a little more costly with longer strings.

Comment: @l4mpi Yes, it's more or less the same idea I've got but doesn't answer me why even the access is slower. The result is that, when it's possible, I try to use max 30 char lenght for large dictionaries

Comment: @AlexF I said *may* not; string hashing does involve the length of the string, see http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm