# efficiency of long (str) keys in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm parsing some xml (with some python 3.4 code) and want to retrieve both the text from a node and its id attribute. Example:
`<li id="12345"> Some text here </li>`
My current code is structured around the text only (I'm now adding the id, but didn't need this before). I'm looping through a list of text/sentences, and then proceed to do some stuff. So I thought of making a dictionary with the text/sentence as key, and this id attribute as value.

However, this doesn't feel very efficient. The text can be a whole paragraph, making the key very long. Whereas the id is always of a fairly limited length (but still of type str though, e.g. some alpha characters followed by some digits). 
But making the ids the key and the text the value requires some rewriting of the code. All not very problematic, but this just got me wondering: How inefficient would it be to have the text (potentially a whole paragraph) as key, compared to an id like "ulp_887362487687678" as key?

I can just make two reverse dictionaries (one with id as key, the other with text as key) and compare construction and lookup and all. And I've also found some topics on key length limit ([Do Dictionaries have a key length limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464900/do-dictionaries-have-a-key-length-limit)). But I'm merely wondering what your thoughts are on this. Is having such long str keys in your dict something that you definitely want to avoid, or is it not a very big deal?
If you could share some pro's/con's, that would be great!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, Python string length hardly has an impact on dictionary performance. The only influence the string length could have is on the `hash()` function used map the key to a hash table slot.

String length has very little impact on the performance of `hash()`:

```
>>> import random
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> generate_text = lambda len: ''.join([random.choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(len)])
>>> for i in range(8):
...     length = 10 + 10 ** i
...     testword = generate_text(length)
...     timing = timeit('hash(t)', 'from __main__ import testword as t')
...     print(f'Length: {length}, timing: {timing}')
... 
Length: 11, timing: 0.03713229100685567
Length: 20, timing: 0.024632290937006474
Length: 110, timing: 0.020530124893411994
Length: 1010, timing: 0.019442707998678088
Length: 10010, timing: 0.019319916958920658
Length: 100010, timing: 0.01950641698203981
Length: 1000010, timing: 0.019174500019289553
Length: 10000010, timing: 0.0229318750789389
```

I stopped at generating a string of 10 million characters, because I couldn't be bothered waiting for my laptop to generate a 100 million character string.

The timings are pretty much constant, because the value is actually cached on the string object once computed.

There is *one* edge-case that would affect performance: strings with extremely long common prefixes. A dictionary lookup consists of two stages: a hash lookup, which selects a bucket in the dictionary, and then an equality test against any existing keys in that bucket. The equality test could take a lot of time if your keys are not the same object (when `is` is sufficient), are very long, and most of their prefixes are the same. String equality testing [uses `memcomp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43466271), which means the comparison takes O(N) time with N being the length of the common prefix.

```
>>> for i in range(7):
...     length = 10 + 10 ** i
...     testword = generate_text(length)
...     testother = testword[:-10] + generate_text(10)
...     timing = timeit('t == o', 'from __main__ import testword as t, testother as o')
...     print(f'Length: {length}, timing: {timing}')
...
Length: 11, timing: 0.03756483399774879
Length: 20, timing: 0.016259542084299028
Length: 110, timing: 0.023491207975894213
Length: 1010, timing: 0.03878312499728054
Length: 10010, timing: 0.28688233299180865
Length: 100010, timing: 2.5207629159558564
Length: 1000010, timing: 25.976553458953276
```

However, this should be rare. Don't use *extremely* long strings that are likely to start with the same text as keys.

Comment: Any thoughts on the dictionary vs. hash() performance raised by @JackBrennen below? Suggests dictionary performance might be noticeably different from hash alone.

Comment: @BryanP: ah, yes, lookups also execute an equality check (`lookupkey.__eq__(storedkey)`) and *that* can be expensive if your strings are large enough *and* have a large common prefix. That's not a very common case, but in theory it could happen.

Answer (score 4):

The performance of `hash()` is indeed `O(n)` for strings, **but the result** is cached in the string - repeated calls will use the *cached value*. This is possible because strings are *immutable*. Martijn's code uses the *repeating* feature of `timeit` so you cannot see this effect because in the last case, 10000009 times out of 10000010 the hash code is not calculated.

It still is O(n) underneath:

```
import random
from timeit import timeit

for i in range(10):
    length = 10 ** i
    # notice number=1 !!!
    timing = timeit('hash(t)', 't = "a" * {}'.format(length), number=1)
    print('Length: {:10d}, timing: {:.20f}'.format(length, timing))

Length:          1, timing: 0.00000437500057159923
Length:         10, timing: 0.00000287900184048340
Length:        100, timing: 0.00000342299972544424
Length:       1000, timing: 0.00000459299917565659
Length:      10000, timing: 0.00002153400055249222
Length:     100000, timing: 0.00006719700104440562
Length:    1000000, timing: 0.00066680999952950515
Length:   10000000, timing: 0.00673243699930026196
Length:  100000000, timing: 0.04393487600100343116
Length: 1000000000, timing: 0.39340837700001429766
```

The difference is due to timing errors, branch prediction and alike.

Comment: Isn't this including the time to interpret and compile code containing long strings?

Comment: @user48956 no, the string is created in the setup code which is not included in the timing. Also, the code does not contain a long string, instead the setup code is of form `t = "a" * n`

Comment: It would help to include units in the `timing` values.

Answer (score 2):

Python string length can have a very significant impact on dictionary performance, but you have to get into really big strings.

The issue is apparently that once you've found the right hash bucket, you still have to do a string compare to see if you've got a match.  Doing a string compare on two huge strings is expensive unless they're identically the same string object in memory (in which case Python is smart enough to declare equality trivially).

```
>>> import timeit
>>> for i in range(7):
...   dkey = "X" * (10**i)
...   skey = "X" * (10**i)    # Different object; no fast path
...   d = {dkey: 1}
...   tmp = d[skey]           # Hash is now cached on skey object
...   timing = timeit.timeit('d[skey] == 1', globals=globals(), number=1000)
...   print(len(dkey), " timing is ", timing*1000, " microseconds")
... 
1  timing is  0.119031872600317  microseconds
10  timing is  0.1442211214452982  microseconds
100  timing is  0.1361379399895668  microseconds
1000  timing is  0.16252091154456139  microseconds
10000  timing is  0.5145659670233727  microseconds
100000  timing is  5.568335996940732  microseconds
1000000  timing is  63.68113495409489  microseconds
>>>
```

Up to strings around 1000 in length, there's little overhead due to string size.  By the time you get past 10000 in length, dictionary lookup appears to be practically O(N) with respect to string length.

Comment: It's not that the strings have to be long, they need to have a long *common prefix*. E.g. `skey = "x" + "X" * (10 ** i - 1)` is not going to show the same timing issues.

Comment: Every successful lookup has a full length common prefix.  It's the successful lookups that get slow with really long string keys.