# How does python know under the hood that something is equal to something, does it look at their memory location

Tags: python, boolean, equality

I just started python and I understand that when you set a variable equal to a object type like a string, it will make them equivalent but I want to know why is 'abc' == 'abc' True, does it check the memory location of both strings and see that they have the same location? Or does python check the actual inside of the string to see if each character matches the other?

I know this is a basic python question and I understand why the code outputs the results we see, but I want to know how python checks equality when you are just working with data types with the same construct.

```
'abc' == 'abc' #Output is True
'ab' == 'abc' #Output is False
```

Comment: It's the latter of the two options you gave. This has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466106/what-happens-when-you-compare-two-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality operator `==` checks for equality. Are `a` and `b` the same string?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
a == b  # True
a is b  # False
```

There is an `is` keyword that will check the memory location.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
a is b # False
c = a
a is c  # True
```

It is worth noting that strings work a bit differently when used with the `is` keyword.

```
a = '123'
b = '123'
a == b  # True
a is b  # True
```

EDIT: From @Barmar "The reason for the last result is that immutable objects are interned, so it doesn't make multiple copies of equivalent strings."

Comment: The reason for the last result is that immutable objects are interned, so it doesn't make multiple copies of equivalent strings.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that. Thanks for the heads up.