# What is the most efficient way of comparring 2 strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I'm looking for the most efficient way to compare two strings, and I'm not sure which is better: `==` or `in`. Or is there some other way to do it that is more efficient that either of these?

Edit: I'm trying to check for equality

Comment: Until you run into a known performance issue with your code when comparing strings, pick one over the other.  Idiomatically I've seen `==` but again it depends on what it is you're doing.

Comment: You seem to be asking something like "which is more efficient, an apple or an orange?". `in` and `==` don't do the same thing.

Comment: @JohnColeman Gotcha. What other ways are there for testing for equality?

Comment: @wolfy you don't need other ways to test for equality, use `==`. "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."-- Tim Peters, Zen of Python

Comment: I can't imagine a good use-case for something other than `==` for testing for string equality.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks! I'll give that a read

Comment: You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43466106/4996248) of interest.

Answer (score 4):

They do different things.

`==` tests for equality:

```
"tomato" == "tomato"  # true
"potato" == "tomato"  # false
"mat"    == "tomato"  # false
```

`in` tests for *substring*, and can be considered a (probably) more efficient version of `str.find() != -1`):

```
"tomato" in "tomato"  # true
"potato" in "tomato"  # false
"mat"    in "tomato"  # true  <-- this is different than above
```

In both cases, they're the most efficient ways available of doing what they do. If you're using them to compare whether two strings are actually equal, then of course `strA == strB` is faster than `(strA in strB) and (strB in strA)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please define "comparing".

If you want to know if 2 strings are equal, == is the simplest way.

If you want to know if 1 string contains another, in is the simplest way.

If you want to know how much they overlap, considering gaps, you need complicated algorithms. How about a thick book on algorithms? (This is similar to comparing genetic sequences. I think a book on Bioinformatics algorithms would be very useful too. Anyhow, this case is way too complicated for Stack Overflow.)

EDIT:

For equality stick with "==". It's in Python to do its job.

Answer (score 0):

== in Python is there for comparison purpose, while "in" has a wider definition (contains which includes comparison). Generally, precise and clear purpose constructs are the most optimized ones for doing the targeted job, because indirect constructs are generally based on simple and direct constructs, which should make == better in comparison context and less error-prone.