# Get list value by comparing values

Tags: python, django, list

I have a list like this:

```
    data.append(
        {
            "type": type,
            "description": description,
            "amount": 1,
        }
    )
```

Every time there is a new object I want to check if there already is an entry in the list with the same description. If there is, I need to add 1 to the amount.

How can I do this the most efficient? Is the only way going through all the entries?

Comment: you could make data as a dictionary and have the description be the key.

Comment: I would say making description value as key would be a bad idea since descriptions can be of any length

Comment: @bigbounty I have it as a value now? What exactly do you mean? thanks for the help!

Comment: @ewong as bigbounty mentioned, that's not ideal. The description can be 250 char long.

Comment: In that case, you could always make data as a dictionary and the hash of the description as the key.

Comment: @ewong I don't think that explicitly hashing the string improves performance right? This is what `dict` does under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making `data` a dict and using the description as a key.

If you are concerned about the efficiency of using the string as a key, read this: [efficiency of long (str) keys in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150047/efficiency-of-long-str-keys-in-python-dictionary).

Example:

```py
data = {}
while loop():  # your code here
    existing = data.get(description)
    if existing is None:
        data[description] = {
            "type": type,
            "description": description,
            "amount": 1,
        }
    else:
        existing["amount"] += 1
```

In either case you should first benchmark the two solutions (the other one being the iterative approach) before reaching any conclusions about efficiency.