# Do Python strings end in a terminating NULL?

Tags: python

Is there a special character on the end of Python strings? Like it is \0 in C or C++.
I want to count length of string in python without using the builtin `len` function.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no end-of-string character in Python, at least not one that is exposed and it would be implementation dependent. String objects maintain their own length and it is not something that you need to be concerned with. There are several ways to get the string's length without using `len()`.

```
str = 'man bites dog'
unistr = u'abcd\u3030\u3333'

# count characters in a loop
count = 0
for character in str:
    count += 1
>>> count
13

# works for unicode strings too
count = 0
for character in unistr:
    count += 1
>>> count
6

# use `string.count()`
>>> str.count('') - 1
13
>>> unistr.count(u'') - 1
6

# weird ways work too
>>> max(enumerate(str, 1))[0]
13
>>> max(enumerate(unistr, 1))[0]
6
>>> str.rindex(str[-1]) + 1
13
>>> unistr.rindex(unistr[-1]) + 1
6

# even weirder ways to do it
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'$')
match = pattern.search(str)
>>> match.endpos
13
match = pattern.search(unistr)
>>> match.endpos
6
```

I suspect that this is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Using regex to get the length of a string? That's the funniest thing I have seen today.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question that you asked: there isn't a terminating NULL or anything like that on the end of a Python string (that you can see), because there's no way for you to "fall off the end" of a string. Internally, the most popular Python implementation is written in C, so there probably is a NULL-terminated string somewhere under the hood. But that's completely opaque to you as a Python developer.

If you want to get the length without using a builtin function, you can do a number of different things. Here's an option that's different from the others posted here:

```
sum([1 for _ in "your string goes here"])
```

which is, in my opinion, a little more elegant.

Comment: Python probably does NOT use null-termination internally, because strings can contain nulls: '\0' (echos '\x00')

Comment: @JosiahYoder Python strings store their length, so nothing stops you from using the length to tell when you see a null if it's part of the string or it's the null that terminates the string. In fact, CPython strings [*are* null-terminated internally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b063b02eabf91bfd4edc0f3fde7ce8f0ebb392c4/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1466).

Answer (score 1):

```
count=0
for i in 'abcd':
    count+=1
print 'lenth=',count
```

---

other way:

```
for i,j in enumerate('abcd'):
    pass
print 'lenth=',i+1
```

---

`enumerate` is a built in function that returns a tuple (index and value)

For example:

```
l= [7,8,9,10]
print 'index','value'
for i ,j in enumerate(l):
    print i,j
```

outputs:

```
index   value
0        7
1        8
2        9
3        10
```

---

Comment: what does enumerate do? What's the use of j in this code?

Comment: thanks, still one question though, what is the end of string character , if there is any?

Comment: @ayushgp i think there is no end of the string in python

Comment: `max(range(len('abcd')))+1` uses `len()`

Answer (score 1):

Several interesting things I found:

```
s_1 = '\x00'
print ("s_1 : " + s_1)
print ("length of s_1:  " + str(len(s_1)))

s_2 = ''
print ("s_2 : " + s_2)
print ("length of s_2:  " + str(len(s_2)))

if s_2 in s_1:
    print ("s_2 in s_1")
else:
    print ("s_2 not in s_1")
```

The output is:

```
s_1 :  
length of s_1:  1
s_2 : 
length of s_2:  0
s_2 in s_1
```

Here s_1 seems like a ' ' and s_2 seems like a '' or a NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no**, they are [length-prefixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Length-prefixed), meaning they store their length before the text data begins. Your string can contain as many null characters as you want:

```
>>> len('\x00\x00\x00')  # a string made up of 3 null characters
3
```

---

The long answer is that strictly speaking (on CPython) **yes**, under the hood, strings are also null terminated because CPython is written in C and in C strings are usually null terminated.

If we look at the source code of [`PyUnicode_New(size, maxchar)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_New) which allocates space for a new string in [`Objects/unicodeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f42a06ba279c916fb67289e47f9bc60dc5dee4ee/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1454), we can see that we pass it `size`, the number of characters we intend to store in the string, but then it allocates space for `size + 1` characters:

```c
    obj = (PyObject *) PyObject_Malloc(struct_size + (size + 1) * char_size);
```

and then depending on `char_size` we set that extra character at the end to a 0 of the appropriate size. `char_size` is how many bytes each character should take up and can be either 1, 2 or 4. It's set from the second argument we pass in, `maxchar` and has to do with how Python strings work: if your text contains only ASCII characters, each character will only take up 1 byte, if your string contains at least one emoji, all characters will use 4 bytes each.

If `char_size` is `1`:

```
        ((char*)data)[size] = 0;
```

and if `char_size` is 2 or 4:

```c
        if (kind == PyUnicode_2BYTE_KIND)
            ((Py_UCS2*)data)[size] = 0;
        else /* kind == PyUnicode_4BYTE_KIND */
            ((Py_UCS4*)data)[size] = 0;
```

So CPython strings actually have 1, 2 or even 4 terminating nulls.

This terminating null is not exposed to you when you're coding in Python though. You can tell that it's there if you look at how much memory is used by an empty string:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof('')
49
```

That's 48 bytes for the struct (the metadata of the Python object) + 1 byte for the terminating null.

Answer (score 0):

Came here for the answer,
Now posting what I found:

```
def rec_len(s, k = 0):
try:
    c = s[k]
    return 1 + rec_len(s, k + 1)
except:
    return 0
```

print(rec_len("DoIt"))