# Processing raw data read from serial port with Python serial library?

Tags: python, serial-port, readline, pyserial, raw-data

I am not a Python programmer but am rather electronic circuit designer, however this time I must process some raw data sent by a microcontroller via RS232 port towards Python script (which is called by PHP script).

I've spent quite a few hours trying to determine the best ways of reading raw bytes from serial (RS232) port using Python and I did get the results - but I would like if someone could clarify certain inconsistencies I noticed during researching and here they are:

**1:**
I can see a lot of people who asked similar question had been asked whether they are using `serial` or `pySerial` module and how did they install the serial library. I can only say I don't really know which module I am using as the module worked out-of-the-box. Somewhere I read `serial` and `pySerial` is the same thing but I cannot find if that is true. All I know is I am using Python 2.7.9 with Raspbian OS.

**2:**
I've read there are `read()` and `readline()` methods for reading from the serial port but in the [pySerial API docs](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) there is no mention of the `readline()` method. Futhermore, I discovered the 'number of bytes to read' argument can be passed to `readline()` method as well as to the `read()` method (and works the same way, limiting the number of bytes to be read) but I cannot find that to be documented.

**3:**
When searching for how to determine if **all** of the data from the RS232 buffer has been read I have [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15615/reading-data-from-external-device) found the following code:

```py
read_byte = ser.read()
while read_byte is not None:
    read_byte = ser.read()
    print '%x' % ord(read_byte)
```

but that results with the:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testread.py", line 53, in <module>
    read_all()
  File "./testread.py", line 32, in read_all
    print '%x' % ord(read_byte)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

upon reading the last byte from the buffer and I was able to detect the empty buffer only with the following code:

```py
while True:
    c = rs232.read()
    if len(c) == 0:
        break
    print int(c.encode("hex"), 16), " ",
```

so I am not sure if the code that didn't work for me is for some serial library that is other than mine. My code for openinig port is BTW:

```py
rs232 = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 2400,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)
```

**4:**
The data I am receiving from µC is in the format:

```py
0x16 0x02 0x0b 0xc9 ... 0x0d 0x0a
```

That is `some raw bytes + \r\n`. Since 'raw bytes' can contain `0x00`, can someone confirm that is not a problem regarding reading the bytes into the Python string variable? As I understand that should work well but am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PySerial works for me although haven't used it on a Pi.

3: Read() returns a string - this will be zero length if no data is read, so your later version is correct. As a string is not a character, you should use e.g. ord(read_byte[0]) to print the number corresponding to the first character (if the length of the string >0)
Your function:

```
while True:
    c = rs232.read()
    if len(c) == 0:
        break
    print int(c.encode("hex"), 16), " ",
```

Needs something adding to accumulate the data read, otherwise it is thrown away

```
rcvd = ""
while True:
    c = rs232.read()
    if len(c) == 0:
        break
    rcvd += c
    for ch in c:
        print ord(ch), " ",
```

4:
Yes you can receive and put nul (0x00) bytes in a string. For example:

```
a="\x00"
print len(a)
```

will print length 1

Comment: Does 'Yes you can but 0 bytes in a string.', mean: 'Yes you can but *without* zero-bytes in a string.'? What I would like to know is if e.g. `0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x0a` received from RS232 and assigned to a string variable can cause trouble. As I understand the internal string representation are null-terminated C strings but I can't find if zeroes can be stored at the high level representation nevertheless of the internal representation.

Comment: The internal representation of strings in the usual Python we use on Linux/Windows isn't nul-terminated. You can put any value characters in a string.

Comment: That would mean this [voted-up anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24409793/1324175) saying: '*Internally, the most popular Python implementation is written in C, so there probably is a NULL-terminated string somewhere under the hood.*', is wrong?

Comment: BTW, I can't **anymore** edit (during first 5 minutes after posting) or delete my own comments since there is no x icon (or anything) on mouse over. The funcion(s) before worked OK but not anymore. The problem is exactly as described [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336797/how-to-delete-my-own-comment-on-stack-overflow#comment407115_336814). Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to leave the comment to confirm the issue. Note: I don't have many reputation points but I do know how editing/deleting own comments funcion worked before.

Comment: That answer is only correct in saying that the string implementation is opaque to the python-writing developer, and definitely wrong about the implementation using nul termination, as Josiah Yoder has commented.

Comment: You can only edit a comment for a few minutes after posting, but you should be able to delete your own comments - I get the X - try different browser?

Comment: Yes, I said the edit is expected to work 'during first 5 minutes after posting'. In the meantime I posted the issue confirmation including screenshots as an 'answer' to the question I mentioned. Since I don't have enough reputation points, posting the 'answer' was the only way I could reply. Judging upon the upvotes I got there are more users affected by this issue. Moreover, a few hours ago the question score was -5 and now the score is +1 meaning others have the same issue. Yes I tried with FF and Chrome and the result was the same - no `X` **anymore**.