# File contents not as long as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open(sourceFileName, 'rt') as sourceFile:
    sourceFileConents = sourceFile.read()
    sourceFileConentsLength = len(sourceFileConents)

    i = 0
    while i < sourceFileConentsLength:
        print(str(i) + ' ' + sourceFileConents[i])
        i += 1
```

Please forgive the unPythonic `for i` loop, this is only the test code & there are reasons to do it that way in the real code.

Anyhoo, the real code seemed to be ending the loop sooner than expected, so I knocked up the dummy above, which removes all of the logic of the real code.

The `sourceFileConentsLength` reports as 13,690, but when I print it out char for char, there are still a few 100 chars more in the file, which are not being printed out.

What gives?

- Should I be using something other than `<fileHandle>.read()` to get the file's entire contents into a single string?
- Have I hit some maximum string length? If so, can I get around it?
- Might it be line endings if the file was edited in Windows & the script is run in Linux (sorry, I can't post the file, it's company confidential)
- What else?

---

[Update] I think that we strike two of those ideas.

For maximum string length, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string).

I did an `ls -lAF` to a temp directory. Only 6k+ chars, but the script handed it just fine. Should I be worrying about line endings? If so, what can I do about it? The source files tend to get edited under both Windows & Linux, but the script will only run under Linux.

---

[Updfate++] I changed the line endings on my input file to Linux in Eclipse, but still got the same result.

Comment: Edited and run on same OS it works perfectly. Can you print `repr(sourceFileConents[i])` and tell if any of the contents have a `\r` character? Are there `100` lines in your source file?

Comment: Have you considered writing `sourceFileContents` to a separate file and then inspecting the two with something like `diff`? If you do this, what do you see?

Comment: What encoding are you using?

Comment: I believe your problem is that read() returns bytes and sourceFileConentsLength is number of bytes, not number of characters. You could convert it to unicode before finding length of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is encoded in something like `UTF-8`, you should decode it before counting the characters:

```
sourceFileContents_utf8 = open(sourceFileName, 'r+').read()
sourceFileContents_unicode = sourceFileContents_utf8.decode('utf8')
print(len(sourceFileContents_unicode))

i = 0
source_file_contents_length = len(sourceFileContents_unicode)
while i < source_file_contents_length:
    print('%s %s' % (str(i), sourceFileContents[i]))
    i += 1
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Python v3.2.3  Exception:  sourceFileContents_unicode = sourceFileContents_utf8.decode(\'utf8\')\n', "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 2):

If you read a file in text mode it will automatically convert line endings like `\r\n` to `\n`.

Try using

```
with open(sourceFileName, newline='') as sourceFile:
```

instead; this will turn off newline-translation (`\r\n` will be returned as `\r\n`).

Comment: A nice theory.  Alas, it did not help :-(