# How to store a really long .txt file as a String in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hey so I am trying to fit the entire text of the Odyssey into a string like this

```
with open('odyssey.txt','r') as file:
    odysseytext = file.read().replace('\n', '')
print(odysseytext)
```

But when I print it out I am only getting the first 598261 characters (checked with len())
Does anyone know why this is happening or how to create a string with a very large amount of text? Thanks

Comment: looks like your file is "only" 598261 characters long. You can have as long strings as you want

Comment: That's about the size of it. Downloading from Gutenberg https://gutenberg.org/files/1727/1727-0.txt, I got 698563 which includes the Gutenberg wrapper text and a fairly long intro by the translator. How big is this file on disk? `print(os.stat('odyssey.txt').st_size)`? it'll be a bit less than that because you remove newlines.

Comment: I can't reproduce a clipped string with 1x or 10x *odyssey.txt* from project gutenberg. The size of a string should only be limited by your [RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40352838/14277722).

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh You are right that is the size of my file, I hadn't noticed that. But when I print out the txt in VScode's terminal it only prints a portion of it. Is there a limit to size of string VScode will print?

Comment: yes, they cut the string so it doesn't start lagging. But I think there should be a button to display the whole output anyway

Comment: Side question: *why* are you trying to make massive strings without any separation?