# .avrs to .csv conversion: Viewing csv as dataframe with cells with extreme number of characters

Tags: python, r, excel, csv

I have some physiological data that was in .avro format that has been converted to .csv files using python. When I go to view the .csv in Excel or load it into R, it seems that the character limit is exceedingly high for one column (which is the column of interest). I cannot even open the .csv file to view how many characters are in the cell (I get an error when opening in Excel).

I thought to also try viewing in python with pandas but am worried about a similar issue with the characters.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Side note: Excel is terrible with CSV files. Also a cell can only contain 32,767 characters.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about running into a character limit when loading the csv files with python/pandas. There is a [theoretical limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string) on the amount of characters in a python string, but it's on the order of quintillions.