# How to determine the practical character limit of a Livy request to submit Spark batch job sent from Airflow?

Tags: pyspark, airflow, livy

I am trying to figure out the upper limit (practical estimate is fine) of characters/bytes passed on as args to the [LivyOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-livy/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/apache/livy/operators/livy.html#LivyOperator) in Airflow.

The operator eventually uses args(`: Sequence[str | int | float]`) as part of the spark_params in the POST request: `self.get_hook().post_batch(**self.spark_params)`.

As there are a lot of steps involved until the Spark cluster receives the original args as arguments, I find it difficult to determine a practical limit when working in Airflow (e.g. pass on de-serialized JSON as part of args).

Assumptions on available sys memory:
server running Airflow  1-3 GB, server running Livy 5-10 GB

My thoughts on limits involved so far:

- inside python: actual value I want to know the limit of -> single str -> python str limit -> dependent on py installation, but in this case practically limited by [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string)
- server hosting Livy: POST request (see [What is the size limit of an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-an-http-post-request)) -> best guess: kB range
- Spark (invoked by Livy obviously) specific limits -> ?
- server specific [cmd line arg limits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) -> best guess: low GB range

Seems like the POST request is the potential bottleneck, but maybe I'm missing something entirely...
Any practical advice highly appreciated.